# null checking of array using question mark break

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have this array of object

`const a = {a:[{b:[{prop: 10}]}]}`

to access the value of 10 I do

`a.a[0].b[0].prop // 10`

I use this fallback, make sure things doesn't break but it didn't work?

a?.a[0]?.b[0]?.prop

, I can use something like lodash's get or check using the old method but how to use the question mark syntax?

Answer (score 7):

Optional chaining should be written as below

`a?.[0]?.b?.[0].prop`

Comment: doesn't work, pls try const a = {a:[{b:[{prop: 10}]}]}

Comment: @AndreThonas Oops I missed one `a` you can try this `a.a?.[0].b?.[0].prop`

Answer (score 2):

This should be foolproof:

```js
const a = {
  a: [{
    b: [{
      prop: 10
    }]
  }]
};

console.log(a?.a?.[0]?.b?.[0]?.prop);
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
a?.a?.[0]?.b?.[0]?.prop
```

Alternatively, you could use `||` operator to get to the desired value.

```
(((a || {}).a || [{}])[0].b || [{}])[0].prop
```